# mySQL Query With Joins and Counts

Tags: php, mysql

I have a my sql DB and using php to access it.

My tables look like:

> Flights Table Flight ID, Time, Airport

Seats Table
Flight ID, Seat Number

I have the following query:

```
SELECT f.FlightID 'ID', Count(*) 'Seats Booked' FROM flights f, seats s  GROUP BY f.FlightID
```

I want the out put to be

> Flight ID    Seats Booked
>
> ID           Num seats book

The problem is currently it shows this:

```
[{"ID":"0","Seats Booked":"37"},{"ID":"1234","Seats Booked":"37"}] (The output is JSON encoded)
```

When it should be be like 10 and 27 if you follow me? It doesnt seem to be the join correctly.

Please give an explanation of what im doing wrong rather than just an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion : Please, do not use space in name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LmC,

You did not use the clause to make the join. Thats why you got a sum for each grouped instruction.

The correct instruction using your syntax should be something like:

```
SELECT f.FlightID 'ID', Count(*) 'Seats Booked' 
FROM flights f, seats s  
where s.FlightId = f.FlightId
GROUP BY f.FlightID
```

Using inner join syntax should be something like:

```
SELECT f.FlightID 'ID', Count(*) 'Seats Booked' 
FROM flights f
inner join seats s  
on  s.FlightId = f.FlightId
GROUP BY f.FlightID
```

You can do the something without using the flight table. The flight table is not making any difference because you are returning a group of flightid. And the table seats has flightid. The statement below should be enough. This is true if you are not concerned about flights without booked seats

```
SELECT s.FlightID 'ID', Count(*) 'Seats Booked' 
FROM seats s  
GROUP BY s.FlightID
```

If you wanna show flights without booked seats, then you should use left join to flights. The statement below will solve this issue.

```
SELECT f.FlightID 'ID', Count(*) 'Seats Booked' 
FROM flights f
left join seats s  
on  s.FlightId = f.FlightId
GROUP BY f.FlightID
```

Comment: Why is this better than an inner query? Which preforms better?

Comment: I edited my post. Take a look in the last statement. You do not need the join to retrieve only the flights booked and the seat count

Comment: @JoseAreas If he wants the seats booked from *all* flights, then he would want the JOIN to ensure that he gets the seats booked only where the flightID exists in the flights table

Comment: You are absolutely right @Evan. However, we must assume some basic rules. If the field flightid on table seat is a foreign key of flightid on table flights, it is not possible we has any flightid on seat without a reference on flights. If he wants to show flights without booked seats, then, we should provide him with a left join. You know what I mean? I updated my answer to add this option.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need anything more than Flight ID from flights table, why not just doing this:

> SELECT s.FlightID, COUNT(s.id) FROM seats s GROUP BY s.FlightID

If you also need to calculate flights with no seats, use this:

> SELECT f.flightID, COUNT(s.id) FROM flights f LEFT JOIN seats s ON
>   s.flightID=f.flightID GROUP BY f.flightID

Comment: Because a join will select the all seats from Seats table where the flightID exists in the flights table.

Comment: you're right. If zero seats are needed, then only using join of course. But inner join is not a solution for that anyway

Comment: I updated my answer. LEFT JOIN should be used here to take into account flights with 0 seats

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use the join syntax shown below as your syntax is somewhat outdated.
Second, be sure to include the `where` clause

```
SELECT f.FlightID 'ID', count(*) as "seat count"
INNER JOIN seats s On
f.FlightID = s.FlightID
Where f.FlightID = 'some_id'
GROUP BY f.FlightID
```

Comment: Ahh i get it now, So it requires an inner query? Why is this? Is it possible to do it without one? Great answer!

Comment: @LmC If you don't use the sub-query, count is going to simply select the count of total rows returned by the *entire* query, and use that for each row.

Comment: So this is the best way to do it then?

Comment: @Evan: it would be a performance hit since you are putting select statement in the select statement. It will get executed for each retrived record. See my solution.

Comment: @LmC You can either go the sub-query approach or use the `where` clause in the original query

Comment: If you don't need anything more than Flight ID from flights table, why not just doing "SELECT s.FlightID, COUNT(s.id) FROM seats s GROUP BY s.FlightID" ?

Comment: @LMC I actually mis-read the question, you will not need to use the subquery in this case (as many others have pointed out)

Comment: You don't even need a join, there is everything you need in the seats table.

Comment: @piotrm Based on how I read the question, he wants a count for *all* flights, so that would be incorrect what you said.

Comment: Inner join won't show anything that is not in seats anyway. If you wanted flights without bookings you would need left join with coalesce().

Comment: @piotrm It's possible to have rows in seats that no longer refer to a flight, for whatever reason. Using an inner join ensures that all records from seats exist in flights.

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem with your approach is you are not joining your tables. What i mean by joining is "Table1" is related to "Table2" with some relationship. In your case it is flight id. So in the other table (Seats table) you will have seats data but that would be available for any specific flight. Therefore in order to have the matching records you need to join that two tables based on flightid so that you get different number of seats for each flight.

Try this sql.

```
select f.flightid as 'id', count(s.seat_number) as seats_booked
from flight f, seats s
where f.flightid=s.flightid
group by f.flightid
```

Comment: Why is this better than an inner query? Which preforms better?

Comment: it is neither better nor worse. It is just an alternative syntax, does exactly same thing as inner join

Comment: @LmC : in any sql statement execution starts from bottom and selection of the rows occurs at the last. So in your solution when selection is happening another sql is getting executed. so it will take more time to execute. should avoid such practice.